# jquery filter records that have range between x and y no

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I am trying to make jquery based search engine from xml file.... now I need to get all the properties with price range between x and y.... I am using filter function but i am doing something wrong or missing something. To test I am comparing just value from my xml record and following code should bring one record only but not... many thanks in advance !

```
 function searchProperties() {

          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "propertyXMLData.xml",
              dataType: "xml",
              success: function (xml) {

                  $(xml).find('property').each(function () {

                      x_priceask.push($(this).find('priceask').filter(function () {
                          return $(this).text() == 229,995;

                      }));

               }); //end Ajax call

                  alert(x_priceask.length);

                  for (i = 0; i <= (x_priceask.length - 1); i++)
                  {
                      alert(x_priceask[i].text());
                  }
              },
              error: function () {
                  alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
              }
          });
      }
```

i have tried like following but still not working!

```
$(xml).find('property').each(function () {

 x_priceask.push($(this).find('priceask').filter(function (index) {
        var value = parseInt($(this).val());
        return value==229,995;

                      }));
```

Comment: `return $(this).text() == 229,995;` is not a valid syntax, it should be `return $(this).text() == '229,995';`

Comment: Can you also share the response xml

Comment: yes you was right ... it was very silly mistake ...

Comment: but you can simplify it further using filter() as I gave in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function searchProperties() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "propertyXMLData.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

            var x_priceask = $(xml).find('property').filter(function(){
                return $(this).find('priceask').text() == '229,995';
            })

            alert(x_priceask.length);

            for (i = 0; i <= (x_priceask.length - 1); i++)
            {
                alert(x_priceask[i].text());
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });
}
```